# Why are macros evaluating differently than const int?

Tags: c, macros, constants

I'm coding for a dspic33 micro controller in C using MPLAB IDE.

These 2 code segments give different values for pwmOut_period. With const long, it works fine, with macros it gives the wrong value. Why is this?

```
const long PWM_FREQ = 25000; //Frequency of output PWM Voltage and Temp 
const long PWM_CLOCK_FREQ = 500000000; //500Mhz PWM clock inside uC
pwmOut_period = PWM_CLOCK_FREQ / PWM_FREQ;

#define PWM_FREQ 25000 //Frequency of output PWM Voltage and Temp 
#define PWM_CLOCK_FREQ 500000000 //500Mhz PWM clock inside uC
pwmOut_period = PWM_CLOCK_FREQ / PWM_FREQ;
```

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Please update your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: What is `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(long)`? Try `500000000L` to make it clear it is a long int.

Comment: @Schwern: The type of an integer constant is automatically wide enough to represent its value.

Comment: Edit the code to provide a [mre], including showing the values resulting for `pwmOut_period`. If it is not feasible for us to reproduce directly, since many readers will not have the necessary hardware and software, provide a compilable piece of code (a **minimal** piece of code that is compilable) and show the assembly language the compiler generates for it.

Comment: Print the output of `sizeof(long)` on your board, and tell me the result. What type is `pwmOut_Period`? It almost seems like your system is using a `sizeof(long)` of `2`.

Comment: "give different values" why don't you show them? Together with the code that defines the variable that holds the result and how you print it.

Comment: It dsPIC33 another one of those oddball architectures with 16 bit bytes? If so I strong recommend picking a better designed ISA. But 16 bit bytes would surely explain all manner of odd and non-traditional behavior with really stupid possibilities such as 2 byte `long` types.

Answer (score 0):

Macros are expanded in preprocessor to literals. Unsuffixed integer literals are of type `int`, `long int`, or `long long int`, depending on which smallest type of those the value can fit in.

In this case I pressume, that `int` type was used. Division of two `int`s may result in different value than dividing two `long`s.

Comment: It is not up to the compiler what the types of the literals should be. For an unsuffixed decimal constant, C 2018 6.4.4.1 5 says it is the first of `int`, `long int`, or `long long int` that can represent it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right. I will update the answer.